# Removed www subdomain and now app cannot locate assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I just built a new version of my website and when I kept the old version still running at `v1.domain_name.com`.  The new app has taken `domain_name.com` and `www.domain_name.com`.

When the old version loads, it's still looking to for files at `www`:

```
Request URL: https://www.domain_name.com/assets/application-ac351bca8a3fa2a33d1cb8f4c9cc40ac84207be5f2dfd46e9040019626608098.css
```

How might I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the asset host in the config

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#cdns

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'v1.domain_name.com'
```